# Append the changes in list of files to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

Problem Statement: -
I want to extract the filenames with their timestamp to a csv or excel file from an UNC path in windows. The content of folder location may change and hence I want to capture the day when the filename was added to the output file. The output file should only append the changes that happened from last time. For example, if more files got added to the location those should be captured but if some got deleted they should be as it is in the output file.

Expected Output: -

[image: Expected_Output]

Code Created so far: -

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\UNC_Path\DEV\REQUEST\SCD\ARCHIVE\*.txt |
    Select-Object -Property Name,LastWriteTime |
    Export-Csv -Append -Path \\UNC_Path\DEV\REQUEST\SCD\ARCHIVE\Output.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

This gives an output like below: -

[image: Current_Output]

Can someone guide me to append only the changes and add date column when particular row was captured. I am a newbie to both powershell and stackoverflow. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: if abc.txt changes tomorrow, do you want to update the existing record or add an additional record, so there would be two entries for that file? Also, does this need to recursively check sub folders of the original path?

Comment: Hi Joel. If the name changes, then the current name to be remain as it is and the output will add the new name with new time. Folders are not required to be looked recursively.

Comment: What if it's not the name that changes, but the contents? Should that change the "LastWriteTime" value of the existing record or add a new record?

Comment: Good Point. However, I do not want to look at the contents of file. If the file name does not change, then output should capture the latest LastWriteTime which is equivalent to "Last Modified Time". In this case, the existing file name would remain as it is but the "DayWhenNameAdded" and "LastWriteName" would get changed.